# how to display errors notice in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

Hi I have the following code in my model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_destroy :check_tasks
    has_many :tasks, :order => 'created_at DESC'
  validates :name, :presence => true
  belongs_to :sprint
  validates :sprint_id, :presence => true
     def check_tasks
        if self.tasks.any?
          errors.add_to_base "Product has tasks and cannot be destroyed."
  return false
end
end
end
```

When I am in the product view which lists all the products, I would like to display the error message on the top of the view, every time someone tries to delete a product which has tasks linked to it. I want the message: Product has tasks and cannot be destroyed displayed.

What code should I put in the view below? The view is the product view, which is in the views/products folder.

Thanks!!!

```
<h1>Listing products</h1>
<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path %>
<table>
  <tr>

    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Sprint</th>    
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
<% if not @messages_rendered -%>
  <% if flash[:error] -%>
    <p class='error'><%=h flash[:error] %></p>
  <% end -%>
  <% if flash[:notice] -%>
    <p class='notice'><%=h flash[:notice] %></p>
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
<% @messages_rendered = true -%>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= product.description %></td>
    <td><%= product.sprint.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try putting this in your product_controller:

```
def destroy
  ...
  flash[:error] = @product.errors.full_messages.join(' ')
  ...
end
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! The only thing is that I get baseProduct has tasks and cannot be deleted. Do you know how I can delete the "base" behind the text?

Comment: @Runy I guess, you're using ruby 1.8, right? I have updated the code, try this one.

Comment: Yes I got ruby version 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.5. I tried the code you updated but it did not work. Strange that the "base" keeps showing up. I'm almost there. I know it.

Comment: @Runy and why do you call `.add_to_base` in the first place? Couldn't you just `add`?

Comment: I tried with just errors.add("Product cannot be deleted because it has tasks") but it did not work. errors.add seems not to be a good command. Does that work in your code? Thank you very much, for your help it already helped me a lot. I have been searching this for 2 months now to get to the next level with my app.

Comment: they say that errors.add_to_base needs to be used when you do not want to add an error to a field. add_to_base is when you just want to add an error which is not related to a specific attribute of your model.

Comment: @Runy ah, yes, they're right. I don't really understand why that code doesn't work. But try this: `@product.errors.on_base()`